# Returning a string in C without pointers?

Tags: c, string, pointers, return

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_string(char prompt[], char returned[], int MAX)
{
fputs(prompt, stdout);
fflush(stdin);
fgets(returned, MAX, stdin);
}

main()
{
    char string[0][10];

read_string("String you want to return ", string[0], sizeof string[0]); 

printf("The returned string is %s",string[0]);

fflush(stdin);
getchar();

}
```

This code is from an exercise I made (modified),just indicating the line of code I can´t understand very well. Its suppose to return various strings within a loop, hence I just declared the STRING [0][100], since its just an example.

Well I understand that the variable "string" gets in the function like this
string = returned
Then after getting the string from the keyboard (fgets) how does it return to the main(), I mean does it really go back and implicitly do this?
returned = string

Also the compiler gives me this message when compiling (although it does really return me a string when running)

[Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

I´m new in learning functions and their structure, I haven´t seen pointers yet,but from what I´ve read so far you need pointers to return strings. Excuse any terrible mistakes and its poorly written code I´m very grateful with any guidance on solving this issue.

The question in here mainly is about how does the string return, without needing to use ***return***, I mean the string gets saved in the variable called "returned" but how does it get out of it, and get back in main.

Comment: Indeed I did not explicitly asked the question. The question in here mainly is about how does the string return, without needing to use *return*

Comment: This line in `read_string()` is plain weird: `(prompt, stdout);`.  It evaluates `prompt` and throws it away; it then evaluates `stdout` and throws that away too.  The code can be omitted without any change to the external behaviour of the program.

Comment: That was actually an error on my behalf, I meant to put
    **fputs(prompt,stdout);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you can not really pass an array as an argument to a function. When you call `read_string("String you want to return ", string[0], sizeof string[0]);` what really happens is that the array parameters to `read_string` are *aliased*. It means that if and when `read_string` modifies `prompt` or `returned` the caller’s first or second (`string[0]`) argument string are also modified. That’s the way `read_string` can return the string to the caller.

This can also come and bite you, for example if `read_string` tried to modify the `prompt` array (as in `prompt[0] = 'X'`), it would also try to modify `"String you want to return "`. In standard C modifying such a string literal gives undefined behavior. Many compiler will put this kind of string literal in readonly memory and this will abort your program.

Note that the line `char string[0][10];` is invalid as 0 sized arrays are not supported in C. You want `char string[1][10];`

Answer (score 4):

```
char string[0][10];
```

declares a zero-length 2-D array. It's illegal to have zero lengths arrays in C.

**6.7.5.2 Array declarators**

> If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array),
>   the  expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a
>   constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.

Not sure what `(prompt, stdout);` is supposed to do.

You are passing a zero length and trying to write into it.

---

Note that fflush`(stdin)` is undefined behaviour in C.

If I understand correctly, you want to display the first string in the prompt and read another one and return it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void read_string(char prompt[], char returned[], int MAX)
{
fputs(prompt, stdout);
fgets(returned, MAX, stdin);
}

int main()
{
char string[10];

read_string("String you want to return ", string, sizeof string); 
printf("The returned string is %s",string);
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Note that `fgets` reads the newline into the buffer which you may want to strip off.

Comment: It´s only functionality is too display any string you enter in the first argument of the function(in this case "String you want to return ")

Comment: One of the main issues I see I´m having has to do with Array declarators, I´ll have a read on them too. Thanks on clearing me some important points on this whole matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some various issues in your code, that KingsIndian has pointed out. I've also never seen the `(prompt, stdout);` syntax used before.

In regards to strings being returned. They aren't. You're declaring an array of characters, and then passing a pointer of this to the function_read string. This is writing its result to that memory location.

So your original string (which would be nulls or garbage) is being over-written by the user input :)

Comment: So let me try to understand this correctly, basically the function is writing the result on the memory location I pointed out wich is *string*

Comment: More or less. Arrays and pointers in C are very closely linked. char string[10]; Is the same as char* string = malloc(10);

Your variable "string" is actually a pointer to the first character in the array.